# DCP inside DCP behaving like an Static CP (Razor Mediator)

Tags: 2013, publishing, razormediator

We have a dynamic Component Presentation, inside which we are using a `helper` function.
This `helper` function calls a `RenderComponentPresentation("tcm:1-2", "tcm:1-4-32")`.

The Component Template tcm:1-4-32 happens to be a dynamic one, but it is behaving like a static Component Presentation; no TCDL tag is being written out (the results are written out directly). Therefore, no changes are being updated when publishing component "tcm:1-2."

Comment: Not sure how the Razor Mediator does its version of `RenderComponentPresentation` but to be sure, does is the Component Template reference the schema for `tcm:1-2` and is checked in? Check with the [Razor Mediator site](https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/) or @AlexKlock--I couldn't find anything that confirmed RenderComponentPresentation changes  into matching tcdl syntax. Does the RenderCP call work on pages?

Comment: I guess the first thing to do is to check if this is the case with the OOTB DW mediator - Two simple CTs using DW should be enough to check what's going on. If you can reproduce it with DWT then perhaps something else is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the razor mediator just uses the RenderComponentPresentation method of the Tridion Engine, so it should just work the same as for the DWT mediator. I haven't had time to dive into the details, but if you want to do so yourself, I'd start here: https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Models/ComponentPresentationModel.cs#156

Beyond that - if you think this might be a bug in the razor mediator, please report it at https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/issues/list

I'd strongly recommend downloading the entire project and loading it in Visual Studio. It's not difficult code for an experienced programmer to follow (thanks @alex-klock) and you may very well be able to figure out the answer for yourself. If you have a proposed fix, please submit it to the google-code project - there are several committers who may be able to make the time to review it.